# One storyboard for few view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have a storyboard, and it needs to be used in few places. Is there any other option than just duplicate storyboard and assign it to new view controller? I want to avoid boilerplate code and writing 3x same outlets and others. I need exactly same layout and almost all functions in all three controllers, but I want to only change model for all of them.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

//outlets
// code
// tableView configuration

}

class SecondViewController: FirstViewController {

// and here I have just overrided some function to modify them

}
```

Comment: I think you’re looking for an `xib` file and not a storyboard.

Comment: As posted, I agree with @Jake. Here's a second option (maybe a third?) - remember, a Storyboard is **not** something that cannot be duplicated in code. (Same with a XIB.) Truth be told, **both** are just a way to assist you from writing code! You are working with an OS that (at it's base) has existing for 30 years, and a language that has quickly become mature.... So let's talk code. First, inheritance. You really didn't give a specific example but you did talk about overrides. So start with your view controllers - in IB talk they **may** be equivalent to a XIB.... /1

Comment: .... Second, let's talk UIKit and Xcode. (You also didn't tag this SwiftUI, which *could* present some differences.) Could a framework project help you? Hard to say, as your question is weak on specifics. But what a framework **can** do, properly done, is reduce a ton of code duplication - something you are clearly wrestling with. And yes, sometimes a framework project can do UI, not just Model (and yep, Controller also).